# How to create local alert notification in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I want to give local alert to the user .I am creating price based app ,user will set a amount and if user sets amount is equal to actual amount app will give alert to the user in background , foreground. I am using api for getting actual amount .I want to create this functionality locally.
How app will give the alert?

Answer (score 0):

The package [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) is what you're looking for. It will help you in creating local notifications as the name suggests and there's plenty of documentation on how to use it.